# Where can I find an online Talmud with interlinear text?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, translation, talmud-bavli

I would like to examine the Babylonian Talmud interlinearly. That is, it has both the original language and English near one another. The biblical interlinears that I have seen are usually line-by-line. They have a Hebrew text on one line and then the next line will be English, breaking down each word from the Hebrew line.

Online, I have [found](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Talmud/talmudtoc.html) [English](http://halakhah.com/) [editions](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/talmud.htm) of the Talmud and [Hebrew/Aramaic](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l0.htm) [editions](http://www.e-daf.com/), but not interlinear ones.

While interlinear editions *might* be available in print for the Talmud (I haven't found the full set yet), I haven't yet found one online. I have found different books like [Siddur and others](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/ina.html). Does anyone know where I can find an interlinear Babylonian Talmud online?

Comment: Not online as in free-in-browser, but the [Artscroll Talmud app](http://www.artscroll.com/app) allows (according to its advertising; I haven't tried it) the user to tap a phrase and automatically hilight its translation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following site uses the Soncino translation: http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Shabbath&df=28b

Comment: This is not interlinear...

Answer (score 9):

http://www.themercava.com/dafyomi

This is a website which has the translation of each phrase in gemara as one hovers over the phrase, not sure how much of the Gemara they have done though.

Comment: Cool site! [15 char]

Comment: A Daf Yomi website that's actually good? WHAT!?

Answer (score 6):

http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.2a

hope this is helpful to you

regards